# Один ко многим Entity схема

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Мне нужно создать две таблицы через CodeFirst в Entity со связью 1 к многим. Суть такова, что есть пользователь, у которого может быть множество сообщений. И в некоторых случая нужно вывести все сообщения конкретного пользователя. Для этого мне нужно сделать два класса сущностей, но вот не могу понять как бы это грамотно сделать. Вот мой вариант:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? MessagesId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Messages UserMessages { get; set; }
    }
    public class Messages
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public ICollection<string> UserMessages { get; set; }
        public Messages()
        {
            UserMessages = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

Но чую, что тут что-то не то. Не могу понять что именно. Подскажите кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо у пользователя хранить ссылки на все его сообщения. А у сообщений хранить ссылки на пользователя, который их создал.

Выглядеть код будет так

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //ссылка на сообщения
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Messages = new List<Message>();
    }
}
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Text {get; set; }

    //ссылка на пользователя
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

`UserId` - не принимает `null`, потому что сообщение может быть создано только при наличии пользователя.